# Manipulating view model using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

How can I create functions with `KnockoutJS` which I can call to do some manipulations on the view model?

Model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public int User { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public string ZipCode { get; set; }
   public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

}

public class Product
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var Product = function (Id, Name) {
            self = this;
            self.Id = Id;
            self.Name = Name;
        }

        function Add() {
            viewModel.products.push(new Product(2, "bread"));
        }

        function Remove(product) {
            viewModel.products.remove(product);
        }

        var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
        viewModel.products = ko.observableArray();

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        Add();
        console.log(viewModel.products().length);

        var t = new Product(2, "bread");

        Remove(t);
        console.log(viewModel.products().length);
</script>
```

Adding works like this here, but `function Remove(product)` does not remove the product from the `array`. I don't get errors, the `console` just prints out 1 (in both `viewModel.products().length` calls).

So how do I create proper functions for KnockoutJS to be able to call them anywhere on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see anything obvious with your code, it isn't something like an object being returned in your model and your delete is actually working but the remaining object is the one returned from the model?

I prefer to map the objects when they are read back from the model, to avoid anonymous objects being created like this:

```
var mapping = {
    'Products': {
        create: function(options) {
            return new Product(options.data.Id, options.data.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

This ensures your products are actual Product objects.

You could also check that the json returned from your model is something like this:

```
{ "User": "a", "Address": "b", "ZipCode": "zip", "Products":[{"Id":1,"Name":"jam"}]};
```

Here is the full code working in a jsFiddle (check the console for the output):

http://jsfiddle.net/6qsjz/15/

This shows, one returned from the model, one added then deleted, one product in the collection.

**Update**

You can initialise the collection server-side by changing your model to this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }
    public int User { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

}
```

This means that you won't need to do `viewModel.products = ko.observableArray();` if you take the above approach.

**Update**

You could then refactor it to make it give it better structure (more modular):

```
  var Product = function (Id, Name) {
        self = this;
        self.Id = Id;
        self.Name = Name;
    }

    var mapping = {
        'Products': {
            create: function(options) {
                return new Product(options.data.Id, options.data.Name);
            }
        }
    }   


function ProductsViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;   
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self);

     self.Add = function Add(product) {
         self.Products.push(product);
     }

     self.Remove = function Remove(product) {
         self.Products.remove(product);
     }
}


var data = { "User": "a", "Address": "b", "ZipCode": "zip", "Products":[{"Id":1,"Name":"jam"}]};

    var viewModel = new ProductsViewModel(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    // add
    var product = new Product(2, "bread");
    viewModel.Add(product);
    console.log(viewModel.Products()); 

    // remove
    viewModel.Remove(product);
    console.log(viewModel.Products());
```

Updated fiddle (again view console for output):

http://jsfiddle.net/6qsjz/16/

Comment: Hi, if I don't use `viewModel.products = ko.observableArray();` I get an error about `push` not being a method of the `viewModel` when using `var mapping = ....`. Also, products is undefined in `viewModel.Products`.

Comment: Hi, have you seen the working fiddle? Are you including the mapping library: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js

Comment: I'd also check the knockout version that i'm using against yours. You could take the fiddle code and use it as is. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Yes got both the knockout libs included. It's working now I was just comparing the js code I had before and the one I posted here. It seems that I had to declare product once like this: `var product = new Product(2, "bread");` and then just call `Add(product)` ,  `Remove(product)` in stead of `Remove(new Product(1 "bread"))`.

Comment: One more question if thats okay with you. Looking to this example: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/using-web-api-with-entity-framework,-part-5 They created a function for `ProductViewModel` and placed all the CRUD operations in that function. What the benefit of that? And should I be doing that too?

Comment: Yes, this is good practice. It makes your objects modularized, there are different patterns you can take. I prefer the 'revealing module' pattern, worth looking into. I find syntax seems a weird fit to C-style but is best practice.

Comment: I've added a better structured example for you, cheers for the upvote/accept. :)

Comment: Looks great! It's a bummer that `Product` is always null and doesn't have `push` whatever I try (`Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference`). Even with the code you provided server and client side.

Comment: Can you add what your model is returning as json, you can see it def works in jsFiddle. It should look like this: { "User": "a", "Address": "b", "ZipCode": "zip", "Products":[{"Id":1,"Name":"jam"}]} or if it's an empty product list like this: { "User": "a", "Address": "b", "ZipCode": "zip", "Products":[]}

Comment: Never mind, it's not getting concatenaded. Its a limitation of visual studio itself. I see exactly this: `"Products":[]`

Comment: I think it is a visiblity issue, I would not have your model returned in a function that way. In the updated jsfiddle I pass in the data to the ProductViewModel creation if that makes sense. The ProductViewModel is then used to populate the data within it, if that makes sense. Difficult to explain in text. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
    var t = new Product(2, "bread");
```

This creates an entirely new object.

```
    Remove(t);
```

Since `t` is entirely new, it's not present in `viewmodel.products` (even though a completely different object with identical members is) and consequently nothing gets removed since the `remove` method of an `observableArray` uses object identity if it's passed an object.

You could rewrite `Remove` as

```
    function Remove(product) {
        viewModel.products.remove(function(item) {
          return item.Id==product.Id;
        }); 
    }
```

since passing a function to the `remove` method causes it to remove any items for which the function is true.

There's also a problem in your `Product` constructor:

```
    var Product = function (Id, Name) {
        self = this;
```

`self` is a global here, and for somewhat tricky reasons is actually an alias to `window`. Prefix it with `var`.